# Xamarin Android Fragment show View before ViewModel is ready

Tags: android-fragments, asynchronous, xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I have a problem with await async method. I have a fragment (SalesFragment) which contains TabLayout with two fragments (FirstSalesFragment and SecondSalesFragment). When I showing SalesFragment and there is in TabLayout selected FirstSalesFragment I have there in ViewModel async method which call API and gives me some data. But problem is in FirstSalesFragment I have Microcharts layout and I want show there Chart, but main problem is my entries for chart are from async method from Api and OnCreateView method just doesnt wait for my async method in ViewModel.

My FirstSales view just show but chart is empty because OnCreateView doesnt wait for Entries... I tried OnActivityCreated or OnStart method but its same...

**My SalesFragment**

```
public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            _view = base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

            var viewPager = _view.FindViewById<ViewPager>(Resource.Id.viewpager);
            if (viewPager != null)
            {
                var fragments = new List<MvxViewPagerFragmentInfo>
                {
                    new MvxViewPagerFragmentInfo(ViewModel.FirstSalesTab, typeof(FirstSalesFragment), typeof(FirstSalesViewModel)),
                    new MvxViewPagerFragmentInfo(ViewModel.SecondSalesTab, typeof(SecondSalesFragment), typeof(SecondSalesViewModel))
                };

                viewPager.Adapter = new MvxCachingFragmentStatePagerAdapter(Activity, ChildFragmentManager, fragments);
            }

            var tabLayout = _view.FindViewById<TabLayout>(Resource.Id.tabs);
            tabLayout.SetupWithViewPager(viewPager);

            return _view;
        }
```

**FirstSalesViewModel:**

```
 public class FirstSalesViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        private readonly ISessionInfo _session;
        private readonly IInfoMessageReporter _infoMessageReporter;

        public FirstSalesViewModel()
        {
            _session = Mvx.Resolve<ISessionInfo>();
            _infoMessageReporter = Mvx.Resolve<IInfoMessageReporter>();
        }

        public async Task Initialize()
        {
        }

        public void Init()
        {
            Task.Run(InitializeHourlySales);
        }
        private async Task InitializeHourlySales()
        {
            // Call API async service... initialize Entries here....

        }

        private List<Entry> _entries;
        public List<Entry> Entries
        {
            get { return _entries; }
            set
            {
                _entries = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => Entries);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

**FirstSalesFragment**

```
public class FirstSalesFragment : BaseFragment<FirstSalesViewModel>
    {
        protected override int FragmentId => Resource.Layout.fragment_firstsales;
        private View _view;
        private ChartView _chartView;

        public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            _view = base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
            _chartView = _view.FindViewById<ChartView>(Resource.Id.chartView);

            if (_chartView != null)
            {
                InitializeChart();
            }

            return _view;
        }



        private void InitializeChart()
        {
            var tempEntries = ViewModel.Entries;

            if (tempEntries == null || tempEntries.Count == 0)
            {
                _chartView.Chart = null;
                return;
            }

              var tempChart = new LineChart
                {
                    Entries = tempEntries,
                    LineMode = LineMode.Straight,
                    LineSize = 5,
                    LabelTextSize = 25,
                    AnimationDuration = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5),
                    BackgroundColor = SKColor.Parse("#EEEEEE")
                };

                _chartView.Chart = tempChart;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does your chart gets updated with the data after you get the data from the service?Anyway I don't think you fully grasped the `async` and `await` and how they operate. Surely you can try to get the data on pageload. In xamarin.forms you can use `OnAppearing` method. Or what you can do is to force the call you make to get the data to run on the main thread so the data will come first and than execute the rest of the code.

Comment: @IdevDev no chart doesnt update after I get data from service this is my main problem...

Comment: Does the data even come? Have you tried debugging it?

Comment: Shouldn't you check if the chart is null and not the other way around?? I mean this line `if (_chartView != null)` . I think this should be like this `if (_chartView == null)`.

Comment: when I used this in OnCreateView `var bindset = this.CreateBindingSet<FirstSalesFragment, FirstSalesViewModel>();
            bindset.Bind(_chartView).For(q => q.Chart).To(vm => vm.Chart);
            bindset.Apply();` and in ViewModel I have property Chart instead of Entries it works... but I dont know.... if its best solution

Answer (score 0):

Do your call to your async code in OnResume which supports using async.

I've modified your code sample a bit and made a call to your ViewModel.Init() in OnResume() for FirstSalesFragment.

### FirstSalesViewModel

```
public class FirstSalesViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
       ...
    public async Task Init()
    {
        await Task.Run(InitializeHourlySales);
    }
    private async Task InitializeHourlySales()
    {
        // Call API async service... initialize Entries here....

    }
    .....
```

### FirstSalesFragment

```
    ...
    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        _view = base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        _chartView = _view.FindViewById<ChartView>(Resource.Id.chartView);



        return _view;
    }


    public async override void OnResume()
    {
      base.OnResume();
      await ViewModel.Init();
      if (_chartView != null)
        {
            InitializeChart();
        }
    }
    ...
```